# What is this inductor-like part?

Tags: identification, inductor, passive-components

In a laser printer's power supply board I have desoldered some of these passives. I think it is a inductor, because it's legs aren't exactly aligned and the round body could be the coil.

Does somebody know what it is and can tell me what the text means.

The label says:

```
SHM
X1400~
Y1239~
E222M
```

(The zero looks more like '( )'.)

[image: the part]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a X1/Y1 rated, 2.2nF capacitor. It was probably placed line-neutral for EMC reasons.

Comment: And 222 means 2.2nF

Comment: @venny Added in...

Comment: Can I use it like a standard cap?

Comment: @mischnic I would put it aside for when I need one. That is an expensive part in single piece quantities.

Comment: I have like 20 of them.

Comment: @mischnic Use them if you want to, it's a 2.2nF cap.